# MSSQL where all or a given value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using MSSQL sever.
I want to run stored procedure, to search something.
Here is my code

```
@productID numeric,
@productCode int(10)

select * from product 
where productID = @productID 
and productCode = @productCode 
or productCode =?
```

I want to search `@productCode` in two ways. One if there is data, second if  `@productCode` is null show all.

Comment: if  @productCode is null show all. describe this please..

Comment: This won't work. I am going to assume that ProductId is the primary key AND if you compare on the primary key you will only ever get back at most 1 record. Adding anything else to the WHERE query serves no purpose. You need to update your questions with what it is you are actually trying to return, what characteristics are you filtering your table on.

Comment: Why do you want to write such a stored procedure? It *won't* run faster, if that's what you thought. This is a well-known *bad* technique. At the very least you'd have to recompile the stored procedure each time you run it, losing any plan caching benefit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try following,

> select * from product 
>   where productID = @productID 
>   and productCode = case when @productCode is null then productCode else @productCode end

Comment: It works in single query. But if I join more tables its not working. Any idea?

Comment: Could you please share your query which have multiple tables.

Comment: Got it working, thanks.

Comment: what will happen if the productCode is null (productCode=ProductCode) will not get satisfied?

Comment: This is actually a well-known *bad* technique. The server will cache the execution plan that corresponds to the *first* invocation, which has a very high chance of being *inapporpriate* for different parameter values. For example, if `productCode` is null the first time, the execution plan may *not* use any indexes that cover `productCode`, resulting in a table scan when an index seek would be better

Comment: Oops, this is actually 100% bad - by using `CASE WHEN` with a field, a full table scan is performed *always* and can't be fixed with recompilation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you point to documentation that shows that an _index_ scan will _never_ be used to process this sort of query?

Comment: @KailashBhakuni This looks like a verbose way to write `COALESCE( @ProductCode, ProductCode )`. Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).

Comment: @HABO if you apply a function to a field, a *seek* will never be used. There are *some* exceptions, like applying `cast(somedatetime as date) = @somedate` but that only works because the optimizer is able to rewrite the function as a range query.

Comment: @HABO as for documentation, check [How to Confuse the SQL Server Query Optimizer](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/) and [Catch-all queries](http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/). Short answer: don't write such queries, or at least use the `OR` form and `WITH RECOMPILE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@productCode IS NULL` to achieve your expectation. Also add the proper parenthesis for that condition alone:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE productID = @productID AND 
      (productCode = @productCode OR @productCode IS NULL)
```

Comment: Not working when @productcode is null.

Comment: @user2738563 _second if `@productCode` is null show all_, it means you want to return all the data from the table with out worrying about `productID ` ?

Comment: No, `productID` should be considered, just ignore any constraints on `productCode`

Comment: @user2738563 this query *does* work when `@productCode` is null and ignores `productCode`. Did you try it? *This* form can lead to passable performance too, if you add `WITH RECOMPILATION` to your stored procedure. The `CASE WHEN` form will result in table scans every time

Answer (score 0):

Please use below sql statement in your stored procedure:

```
@productID numeric,
@productCode int(10)

select * from product where productID = @productID and (productName = @productCode or @productCode is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
DECLARE @productID numeric, @productCode int(10)

select * from product 
where 
productID = @productID 
and 
productCode = CASE WHEN @productCode IS NULL then productCode ELSE @productCode END
```

Comment: This forces a full table scan, even when `productcode` is indexed

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use two selects with and IF ELSE block

```
if NOT @productCode IS NULL
    select * from product 
    where productID = @productID 
    and productCode = @productCode 
else
    select * from product 
    where productID = @productID
```

Comment: There are other tables joined. Looking for a solution with out repeating the  query again.

Comment: @user2738563 you are looking for the wrong thing. Just *don't* create such a query, you'll get bad performance no matter what you do. Best case, you'll have to always recompile your stored procedure to be able to use the appropriate indexes

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter @productcode is null then the query should be as below.

```
select * from product 
where productID = @productID 
and (case when @productCode  
is null then 1 else productCode end) = 
(case when @productCode  
is null then 1 else @productCode end)
```

Comment: This results in a full table scan even when `productcode` is indexed. What the OP asked is a bad practice but *this* form results in the worst performance

Comment: I've used case when on both sides of the filter condition will it result in a full table scan yet?

Comment: The optimizer can't use an index if you apply a *function* on the field. That's because the index contains the original values, not the *calculated result*. The optimizer would have to process each row to calculate the function value and compare it to the parameter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos got the point. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In fact, such "catch-all" queries are a very common type or performance bug. This [article](http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) explains what's wrong in detail. [How to Confuse the SQL Server Query Optimizer](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/) discusses this and other similar problems

Comment: So will dynamic sql be an alternative for this?

Comment: A LINQ query on top of your favourite ORM or Dapper is even better. Just *don't* use such queries. Such queries are almost always used for reporting - filling a grid *is* reporting. Create a view to join the tables, restrict the fields and use LINQ or the reporting tool's language to generate the `WHERE` clause